# Choosing Local Port Number

Tags: tcp, winsock

When using TCP under Winsock, is it possible for my client to choose its local port number when connecting?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: @Stephen strict firewall limits usually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You have to bind the socket before connecting.

```
sockaddr_in sin;
memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_port = htons(11234); /* This will be your source port. */

if (SOCKET_ERROR == bind(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&sin, sizeof(sin))) {
    /* Handle error. */
}
```

Comment: Oh, of course. Did not realize you could also bind on the client side. Thank you.