# How client's local port is chosen

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp

How client's local port is chosen?

I know it's possible to [change the port by binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698422/choosing-local-port-number), but how does the default port is chosen? and who chooses it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An unused ephemeral port is chosen. These are usually in the range 32768-65535, but there's usually a kernel configuration that specifies the range.

Comment: On Windows prior to Vista, the default ephemeral port range was 1025-5000, with a Registry setting to change the upper value (but not the lower value). Vista changed the default range to 49152-65535, with a netstat command to change both bounds.